# Why does `options(digits=3)` get ignored in `knitr'?

Tags: r, knitr, digits

When I run the following line by line in R it works fine, but with `knitr` the `options(digits=3)` gets ignored.

Why? Any solutions?

```
<<cor>>=
#mock up data set.
x <- c(rnorm(100))
y <- c(rnorm(100))
z <- c(rnorm(100))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
df$x<- as.numeric(df$x)
df$y<- as.numeric(df$y)
df$z<- as.numeric(df$z)
options(digits=3)
cor(df, use = 'na.or.complete', method = c("spearman"))
@
```

Comment: Did you try running that code in just a clean R session?  I get the same result whether I run in knitr or just directly.  (make sure to add a call to `set.seed` in there to make sure you get the same output)

Comment: Note that my comment essentially boils down to - "knitr doesn't ignore the options - your expectation for what happens in that code just seems to be wrong"

Comment: @Dason I don't know whether I understood correctly. However, in this case I don't worry about the reproducibility. My issue is that I cannot reduce the digits down to three only (and not seven).

Comment: I was asking if you run that code in a normal R session (instead of knitr) you should get the same thing.  This isn't a knitr issue as much as it is an issue of how the digits get handled.  For example if you change it to `options(digits=22)` you should see a big difference in the number of digits that get printed.

Comment: Now I understood. Yes, actually, in both cases I have more than three digits. See below.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution while searching for a different issue. Leave out `options(digits=3)` and use

```
round(cor(df, use = "na.or.complete", method = c("spearman")), digits = 3)
```

Which leaves the question why the `options(...)` doesn't work. But I can happily live with that!

Thanks everyone for their time!

Gerit

Comment: From `?options`:  

‘digits’: controls the number of digits to print when printing numeric values.  It is a suggestion only.  Valid values are 1...22 with default 7.  See the note in ‘print.default’ about values greater than 15.

Comment: "It is a suggestion only." Does that mean it is not a strict measure and hence `option(digits=i)` is only a rough approximation of how many digits result? I would find that odd for such a cool program like R, but with `round(..., digits=i)` I can well work around it. Can you tell I am not a programmer by heart?! Thank you for caring.

Comment: for the meaning of _suggestion only_, I guess you need to ask either R core or someone who understands `./src/main/print.c` in R source; my superficial understanding is only that it may not give you the expected number of digits precisely; for precise control, you need functions like `round()` or `formatC()`